# Apply function at plus one positions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have the following dataframe

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 df=pd.DataFrame(data={'speed':[63.000,65.000,65.000,64.000,63.000],
                        'acc'=[np.nan]*5,'decc':[np.nan]*5})
```

what i want is to fill the 'acc' column and 'decc' column with the following statement:

```
for x in range(len(speed)-1):
     y=speed[x+1]-speed[x]      
     if y>0:
        acc[x+1]=y
        decc[x+1]=0
     elif y<0: 
          acc[x+1]=0
          decc[x+1]=y
     else:
          acc[x+1]=0
          decc[x+1]=0
```

basically iwant to know how i can apply this to dataframe series
and how will i assign the new value at either of the series described above
starting the assingment not from the first row but from the second

Comment: You can use the `shift` method to create a shifted `speed` column and subtract from the original column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with `diff` and `clip`:

```
diff = df['speed'].diff()

df['acc'] = diff.clip(lower=0)
df['decc'] = diff.clip(upper=0)
```

Output:

```
   speed  acc  decc
0   63.0  NaN   NaN
1   65.0  2.0   0.0
2   65.0  0.0   0.0
3   64.0  0.0  -1.0
4   63.0  0.0  -1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use vectorized operation:

```
diff = df['speed'].diff().fillna(0)
df['acc'] = diff.mask(diff < 0, other=0)
df['decc'] = diff.mask(diff > 0, other=0)
```

Note: you can use `diff.abs()` to get a positive value for `decc`:

```
df['decc'] = diff.abs().mask(diff > 0, other=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   speed  acc  decc
0   63.0  0.0   0.0
1   65.0  2.0   0.0
2   65.0  0.0   0.0
3   64.0  0.0  -1.0
4   63.0  0.0  -1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

use `shift` method in Pandas:

```
df['speed_shifted'] = df['speed'].shift(periods=1)  # create a new column that is a shifted version of the speed column

def calc_acc_decc(row):
    y = row['speed'] - row['speed_shifted']
    if y > 0:
        row['acc'] = y
        row['decc'] = 0
    elif y < 0:
        row['acc'] = 0
        row['decc'] = y
    else:
        row['acc'] = 0
        row['decc'] = 0
    return row

df.iloc[1:, :] = df.iloc[1:, :].apply(calc_acc_decc, axis=1)

df = df.drop('speed_shifted', axis=1)
print(df)
```

you will get:

```
   speed  acc  decc
0   63.0  NaN   NaN
1   65.0  2.0   0.0
2   65.0  0.0   0.0
3   64.0  0.0  -1.0
4   63.0  0.0  -1.0
```